# Create list of sequential numbers in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do something which seems like it should be fairly simple, but cannot seem to find information anywhere for R (other languages have plenty of information).

Essentially, all I want to do is create a list of n sequential numbers starting at a by adding b each time.

So if a = 5.5, n = 4 and b = 1, the output would be: c(5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5)

I've tried using rep(), but no luck. I think I am on the wrong track completely. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
seq(from = 5.5, by = 1, length.out = 4)
#> [1] 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>